# Google Script Loop Syntaxis

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I get the last (or the first) 12 values using a loop in Google Script?

```
function gTrend(term) {
  var resp=[];
  var url="https://apitrendscript.appspot.com/interestOverTime?keyword="+term;
  var body=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var data=JSON.parse(body);
  var timelineData=data["default"].timelineData;
  for (var i in timelineData) {
    var tdata=timelineData[i];
    resp.push(tdata.value[0]);
  }
  return resp;
}

function testGTrends(){
  gTrend("mobfish");
}
```

Here is a sample of the data:

```
{"default":{"timelineData":[{"time":"1072915200","formattedTime":"Jan 2004","formattedAxisTime":"Jan 1, 2004","value":[88],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["88"]},{"time":"1075593600","formattedTime":"Feb 2004","formattedAxisTime":"Feb 1, 20004","value":[94],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["94"]},{"time":"1617235200","formattedTime":"Apr 2021","formattedAxisTime":"Apr 1, 2021","value":[98],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["98"]},{"time":"1619827200","formattedTime":"May 2021","formattedAxisTime":"May 1, 2021","value":[100],"hasData":[true],"formattedValue":["100"],"isPartial":true}],"averages":[]}}
```

Comment: You example is incomplete and contains undefined variables.  Please define timelineData. If it's an array then take a look at the slice() method for arrays.  It will return a shallow copy of a portion of an array.

Comment: thanks for your comments, I have added the complete code

Comment: Please provide a sample of body

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if this what you requested. I have trimmed the data so this is just a sample

Comment: That's fine.  It just makes it easier for our volunteers to answer your question.